# coinbase or any other centralized exchanges diametrically opposed to decentralization goals

Tags: coinbase

coinbase or any other centralized exchanges are diametrically opposed to decentralization goals.

What are some decentralized platforms available one can use to avoid using centralized exchanges?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 0):

Decentralized exchanges are coming and some of them are already operational. The biggest challenges they currently face is poor liquidity - too few transactions.

That being said, it looks like there are plenty of them to try at least: https://coinsutra.com/best-decentralized-exchanges-dex/

In addition, for specifically ERC20 tokens, you can use something like EtherDelta / ForkDelta.